# Unable to Update RBAC role using Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

I am using Azure Devops Pipeline.

I create a ServiceConnection in Azure Devops and added an Service Principal in it.

Agent i am using is 'ubuntu-latest'

I created a powershell task in pipeline

```
- task: AzureCLI@2        
  displayName: 'Assign Role'
  name: task_inline
  inputs:
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    azureSubscription: 'AzureConnRM'
    scriptLocation: scriptPath
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    scriptPath: './abc.ps1'
```

In Powershell to update an existing RBAC Role i am running below command:

```
az role assignment update --role-assignment $myjson  --debug --verbose
```

and json which i am passing is

```
$myjson = '{
  "conditionVersion": "",
  "roleDefinitionName": "Contributor",
  "principalType": "User",
  "condition": "",
  "id": "/subscriptions/097ca710-067e-4a70-8ce6-494268568148/resourceGroups/Trial-RG/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/45d7dc3c-4a95-8a1c-bd87-f8a460c6d255",
  "resourceGroup": "Trial-RG",
  "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/097ca710-067e-4a70-8ce6-494268568148/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
  "scope": "/subscriptions/097ca710-067e-4a70-8ce6-494268568148/resourceGroups/Trial-RG",
  "principalId": "8cd5df22-42f4-405e-b3ab-d562eaf1da92",
  "canDelegate": "",
  "description": "Updated",
  "name": "45d7dc3c-4a95-8a1c-bd87-f8a460c6d255"
  }'
```

But get the error:

Error detail: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 3 (char 4)

Comment: think you face the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819537/expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes-when-passing-json-string-to-az

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Toni
--debug helped me see the detailed log.
3 fields conditionVersion,  canDelegate, condition  were not getting set correctly. I removed these properties from my json and it worked.