# How to send Post request in Github Actions under Windows?

Tags: powershell, curl, continuous-integration, github-actions

I need to notify Sentry about new build version when CI made it. I am using `runs-on: windows-latest` for builds and sending requests with a code below:

```
- name: Notify Sentry
run: |
  $VERSION_NAME = "${{  github.ref_name }}"
  $REQUEST = "{`"version`": `"$VERSION_NAME`"}"
  echo $REQUEST
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "$REQUEST" "https://sentry.io/api/hooks/release/builtin/...id.../...token.../"
```

Request looks correct, but it always returns error `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`:

```
Run $VERSION_NAME = "${{  github.ref_name }}"
  $VERSION_NAME = "${{  github.ref_name }}"
  $REQUEST = "{`"version`": `"$VERSION_NAME`"}"
  echo $REQUEST
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "$REQUEST" "https://sentry.io/api/hooks/release/builtin/...id.../...token.../"
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  
{"version": "v1.1.1"}
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   104  100    87  100    17    313     61 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   375
100   104  100    87  100    17    313     61 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   375
{"error":"Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"}
```

In Postman it works well. How to fix this error?

Comment: Try: `$REQUEST = "{\"version\": \"$VERSION_NAME\"}"` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819537/expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes-when-passing-json-string-to-az

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backslash instead of backtick to escape nested double quotes.

Change this:

```
$REQUEST = "{`"version`": `"$VERSION_NAME`"}"
```

to:

```
$REQUEST = "{\"version\": \"$VERSION_NAME\"}"
```

You may use single quotes instead of nested double ones and then use `Replace` function to bulk escape those like this:

```
$REQUEST = "{'version': '$VERSION_NAME'}".Replace("'",'\"')
```

See: [Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes when passing JSON string to Azure CLI (from PowerShell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819537)